# RecycleView отображение элементов

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Добрый день! Использую recycleview при работе со списком новостей. Отдельная новость - содержит 5 полей. 3 Отображаются при просмотре списка, остальные две если зайти в саму новость(планирую так сделать). 
Подскажите, правильно ли стартовать новый интент при переходе в полную новость или можно как-то вывести все 5 полей в отдельный вью без интента?

Comment: можете организовать диалогом

Comment: на самом деле всё зависит от Вас и Вашего желания, а также дальнейшей потребности использования нового открытого окна. Можете отображать как в новом активити или popupWindow или AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от ваших задач и того, как и где расположен список.

1. Если `recycleview` во `ViewPager` то лучше открыть новую активити или диалог, т.к. добавление фрагмента в контейнер `ViewPager`-а может привести ко множеству проблем с последующим воостановление состояния.
2. Если есть желание использовать тот же `ViewPager` для листания детальной информации о других элементах `recycleview`, то надо стартовать активити, т.к. в диалог пихать `ViewPager` не стоит, а во фрагмент точно не стоит, ибо вложенные фрагменты - трудно отлаживаемое [зло](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/)
3. Если `ViewPager` не планируется, то особой разницы между показом полной инфы в новой активити, фрагменте или диалоге нет. Как хотите так и делайте. Можно даже при нажатии просто перерисовать содержимое элемента `recycleview`, добавив туда полей.

Comment: а можете на примере показать пункт3? Что-то не соображу как это сделать?

Comment: @ИванВовк, что именно из 3 пункта?..

Comment: Уже разобрался, не мог понять, как можно перерисовать уже использующийся вид.